# How to coordinate toast and dialog box? Toast partially covers loading dialog box. Can I resize toast?

Tags: android

Here is exact situation.  User signs in, and gets a Welcome Toast that lasts a few seconds AND they are switched to an account page where there is a loading dialog ...  So its kind of ugly because the Toast is going on at the same time as the dialog. Actually it partially covers it.  I want the user to see the Toast and then the Loading Dialog if its still ongoing after the toast is over. ....  So if I could resize the toast dialog to same size location that would work or if I could hide Loading dialog until Toast was over ..

Comment: Maybe you could use `toast.setGravity(gravity, xOffset, yOffset);` to put the toast message out of the way.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest creating a Thread that will wait for the Toast to finish. You start it right after you display the toast.

```
        Toast.makeText(this,"WELCOME TO MY APPLICATION!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        thread.start();
```

In your thread, you wait for (LENGTH_LONG = 3.5) or (LENGTH_SHORT = 2) seconds and then display your dialog box.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(){
         @Override
        public void run() {
             try {
                Thread.sleep(3500); // use 2000 if LENGTH_SHORT is used
                displayDialog(); // toast should have disappeared at this point so you can display your dialog box here
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }  
       };
```